# C++ Console::WriteLine()-like method without .net framework

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Is it possible to write a Console::WriteLine()-like method in C++ without the .net framework?
What i would like to do is something like that:

```
Console::WriteLine("Hello! " + "This PC is " + Convert::ToString(3) + " years old!");
```

The .net framework version looks like you can do char[] + char[] on [msdn.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx)?

---

EDIT: Is there something i could tell GCC? Maybe to use the string-class for ""-declarations rather than char-arrays?

---

EDIT2: I am trying to write my own function. So no, i won't use `cout`.

---

EDIT3: The only real question is if it is possible to do `"Hello! " + "This PC is " + string("3")`. I know that `string("3") + " hello " + "PC!"` works because the `+ Operator` for the string class will add the `string("3")` to `" hello "` and convert it to a `string` and then add `string("3 hello ")` to `"PC!"` and convert it to a `string("3 hello PC!")`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not expecting C++ to work like C#. I just want to try to write some functions in C++ that work like C# functions. Despite that, there is a C++ version of Console::WriteLine() in the .net framework (see the msdn-link).

Comment: @MathiLpHD That "version" is for C++/CLI, **not** native C++.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I know that, that's why i asked if it is possible to write it WITHOUT the .net framework => without C++/CLI

Comment: In C++ you typically use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to format strings. Can be done inline as in `some_function((std::ostringstream() << "Hello" << 3 << "world").str())`

Answer (score 0):

yes, using the  cout stream object from the iostream header:

```
std::cout << "Hello! " << "This PC is " << getPcAge() << " years old!"<< std::endl;
```